# Json Empty Index

Tags: php, json, laravel, ionic-framework

I have a ionic application which sends json data to my api which uses laravel as it's backend.

When the post request is made to my route, I call a method on my controller..

This controller then takes the data and enters it into the database, however sometimes not all the data sent from the ionic application maybe there.

I.e. My laravel application is waiting for First Name, Last Name, Company and sometimes my ionic application will only send off first_name, last_name meaning the index for company is missing.

How do I in my controller check if an index exists?

See my json request:

```
{"data":{"first_name":"Peter","last_name":"tESt"}}
```

See my controller waiting the data request:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $card = NEW card;
    $card->first_name = $request->data['first_name']; 
    $card->last_name = $request->data['last_name']; 
    $card->location = $request->data['location']; 
    $card->save();

};
```

In some cases the location will be included and in some cases it won't be. The application won't send a empty index either.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can check if a key exists in an array using [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

In your example, you could do something like:

```
if (array_key_exists('location', $request->data)) {
    $card->location = $request->data['location'];
}
```